# Google Hangoust stick to the wrong display (monitor) in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: google-chrome, 14.04, google-hangouts

I have multiple displays (dual-monitor configuration).
After a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and installing Google Chrome + Google Hangouts extension, all hangouts windows are opened on display that I do not use a lot.
Is there any way to set Hangouts to open in correct window? (Dragging it to another window every time is very annoying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is trick that can help.
Open System Settings -> Display and set Launcher placement to the monitor you need to stick Hangouts windows. Push Apply button. That all.
Now you can restore Launcher placement option (show it on both screens) with no affect on hangouts.

Comment: I have had this problem on Ubuntu 13.04 and found this solution somewhere in the internet. But I've forgoten it and could not find again. After some experiments I've finaly did it, so I'm sharing this hint here. If you now a better solution, I'm waiting for it =).

Comment: Thanks for this tip, would you mind adding a screenshot? I didn't quite follow what you did to fix this.

Comment: @slm unfortunatly it seems that it does not work in 14.04 anymore. But the main idea was to change unity panel position in display configuration. It was like main display marker earlier.

Comment: Can confirm that this does not work on 14.04+

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the stand-alone Hangouts application, that you can run from the Google Chrome Apps panel

It does work for me and I can select any application available in any of the two monitors. I am using 16.04 now though

[image: Chrome Apps link]

Cheers,
Miguel